# How do I ensure https is used for only some web services in apache tomcat

Tags: spring, web-services, tomcat, tomcat7, cxf

I have deployed few web services in apache tomcat and all web services are accessible by both http and https.  I want few web services to be accessed by https only and not by http.  Is it possible to configure in apache tomcat or cxf or spring framework.

Any help on this would be really useful to me.

Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a HTTP request is secure, simply call [`ServletRequest.isSecure()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html). Then after checking you can redirect to a secure only version or vice versa.

All above can be done in a number of places, but to my taste it is easiest to write a [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) which transparently handles above mentioned check & redirection.

Note: the above method might not work if your Tomcat is behind Apache or load balancer and SSL is terminated early in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `<transport-guarantee>` to `CONFIDENTIAL` in your web.xml allows you to require SSL for certain pages.

It looks like this:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>SSL forwarding</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/secured</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>
      CONFIDENTIAL
    </transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Hope this helps.